# nodejs - how to keep checking if the jwt token is still valid

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

When you are inactive for a period of time in aws, aws will log you out and show pop-up like this.

[image]

I am wondering how aws handles it and how should do it in nodejs

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to handle sessions in NodeJS.

1. Session based
2. Token based

Since you are asking about tokens, you can set expiry time for the created token.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look this article. It may give a solution for you.

https://medium.com/tinyso/how-to-detect-inactive-user-to-auto-logout-by-using-idle-timeout-in-javascript-react-angular-and-b6279663acf2

> When we hear about the timeout, I’m pretty sure that you will think about using setTimeout method in this context. And yes, it’s the simplest way to implement the timeout on the browser by the following steps:
> Call setTimeout(, )
> If users do something on the app (move, click, input), we clear the timeout by using clearTimeout method and then call setTimeout again. However, this solution is just working fine if the users are on a single tab. If they are using our app on multiple tabs, it should be an issue since they are active on the current tab but inactive on the rest. Then we need to find another solution that allows the active state to sync across multiple tabs